# Preventing default Android NFC reader

Tags: android, flutter, dart, nfc

I have this flutter code to get the identifier of the NFC tag when reading. Using nfc_manager package (https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager).

The running device is OnePlus 7 Pro.

```
void _tagRead() {
    NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
      Ndef? ndef = Ndef.from(tag);
      result.value = tag.data;
      print('Tag read: ');
      final String identifier = tag.data['ndef']['identifier']
          .map((e) => e.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0'))
          .join('');
      print(identifier);
      NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
    });
  }
```

The problem is that when successfully reading the tag, the device default reader pops and removing focus from the application. How this kind of behaviour is prevented?

Comment: Don't call `stopSession` until your app leaves the foreground?

Comment: Did you fix this behavior?

Comment: @Petri, do something like this : https://github.com/semlette/nfc_in_flutter/issues/50

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me:

a) place in initState startSession

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
      if (widget.textToWrite.isEmpty) {
        _tagRead(tag);
      } else {
        _ndefWrite(widget.textToWrite,tag);
      }
    }, onError: (error) async {
      setState(() => _errorMessage = '$error');
    }).catchError((e) => setState(() => _errorMessage = '$e'));
  }
```

b) set stopSession to dispose

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    NfcManager.instance.stopSession().catchError((_) { /* no op */ });
    super.dispose();
  }
```